# renamed (more appropriate): header guard would cause struct compile error

Tags: c

Ok I've sorted it out, comments showed me the way.

Thanks to Jonathan Leffler for the idea with gcc -E option and thanks for the hint by Joachim Pileborg, pointing out the issue that sl_stack somehow seemed to be already defined as empty.

I had the problem that

```
// stack implementation using a single linked list
struct sl_stack {
    struct  sl_list* top;
    void    (*push) (struct sl_stack* stack, int value);
    int     (*pop) (struct sl_stack* stack);
    int     (*peek) (struct sl_stack* stack);
    int     (*empty) (struct sl_stack* stack);
};
```

gave me compile errors in following line:

```
void (*push) (struct sl_stack* stack, int value);
```

telling me that it missed the sl_stack definition somehow.

gcc -E gave me the following:

```
# 11 "list.h" 2





    struct sl_list {
        int value;
        struct sl_list* next;
    };




    typedef struct ;
    struct {
        struct sl_list* top;
        void (*push) (* stack);
        int (*pop) ();
        int (*peek) ();
        int (*empty) ();
    };

    struct * init_sl_stack()
```

pointing out the issue Joachim Pileborg pointed out.
I had a quick glance at my files again and well it's embarrassing, but I missed that my header guard defined sl_stack.
Stupid accident that my guard is named the same way as my struct.

But now I'm curious why struct sl_stack clashes with sl_stack? As far as I know I would need a typedef to make sl_stack be recognized as struct sl_stack.

And i would think it works the other way round that sl_stack does not hinder struct sl_stack ...

Comment: When you say "it breaks" what do you mean? Compilation errors? Please edit the question to include the *complete* and *unedited* build log in that case.

Comment: Also, what version of `gcc` are you using?

Comment: "GCC also tells me there is a '{' missing before <asterisk>." - then there's an error **before** the code that you *believe* to be errant. BTW, the struct definition should work just fine.

Comment: Do you have a macro `push` that expands to something odd?  Or `value`?  Have you looked at the output of `gcc -E` to see what the compiler is seeing? (I notice that the pointer-to-function version of the stack has lost the ability to store values, but that's presumably just an editing issue. It is tangential to your immediate problem.)

Comment: Taken in isolation (7 lines of code in a file, no headers needed), the second structure, the one with the function pointers, compiles cleanly.  If it is not compiling cleanly for you, then you have something interfering with the compilation.  I recommend looking at the preprocessed output to see what is going wrong.

Comment: `{' missing before <asterisk>."` How are you including `asterisk.h`?

Comment: Okay, you have edited the question to say you have compilation errors, but you still don't say *what* errors you have. The structure definitions you have shown do not have any errors, the errors have to be somewhere else. But it's impossible to say without seeing the actual errors. ***Please add the actual errors to your question.*** Also, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: While you still haven't shown the actual errors, the preprocessed code *do* show something, namely that you seem to `#define` the identifier `sl_stack` to nothing. That means that the preprocessor will replace all places where it finds `sl_stack` with nothing, which is what I'm seeing in that code. In the future, please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the error. What I'm doing is only *guessing* as we don't have all information (the complete source).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you might want to make some answer of your comments and i'll select it as it helped me sort the problem out.
Though i think the question needs a title change, but i can't come up with something useful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per most recent edit, it's now clear that your header guard reads:

```
#ifndef sl_stack
#define sl_stack
... contents of header ...
#endif
```

The second line defines `sl_stack` to expand to nothing at all.  If you were to then write the token sequence:

```
int x sl_stack = 3 sl_stack sl_stack + sl_stack 4;
```

the compiler would "see", after `#define` expansion, the new sequence:

```
int x = 3 + 4;
```

Each `sl_stack` instance has simply vanished (or more precisely, been replaced with nothing but causing a token end, which may require inserting a blank to show properly).

Therefore:

```
struct sl_stack {
```

became:

```
struct {
```

which is syntactically valid but defines an *unnamed* structure, and:

```
void    (*push) (struct sl_stack* stack, int value);
```

became:

```
void (*push)(struct * stack, int value);
```

(which is not quite the same as you shown in your `gcc -E` output, but would produce the error message in the original question).

One way to fix it is to use some other name (such as `H_STACK`) as the header guard name.  Another is to use:

```
#define sl_stack sl_stack
```

which tells the compiler that when it sees the token `sl_stack`, it should replace it with the new token `sl_stack`.  The replacement is left alone<sup>1</sup> here, so the new token remains unchanged after that.  By replacing it with itself, you achieve the "no change" effect, and yet `#ifdef` will tell you that `sl_stack` is in fact defined.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is an oversimplified explanation of the actual rules, but good enough for this particular usage.

Answer (score 0):

This:

`struct * init_sl_stack()`

Should be:

`struct sl_stack *init_sl_stack()`

Comment: How does this differ from the code in the question? How does this explain the unexpected syntax error?

Comment: I guessed there could be something wrong with the allocation, that's why I included the code for the factory function... I just updated my answer in order to remove redundant code. Regards